# Loading sub-records for each item in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, master-detail

I'm making an app in which the user can log simple timesheet-like transactions into a list. I have done this with a listview which is connected to a sqlite query with a custom CursorAdapter descendent. So far it is working well.

What I am trying to do next is let the user add any number of "tags" to an individual transcation (think labels against emails in gmail). I have a many-many-relationship table to link tags to transactions, but i'm unsure how to modify my existing listview and cursor arrangement so that each individual record can load and display its tags.

One thing that comes to mind is to load all the data into a two-tiered object structure, then use that as the datasource for the listview. I don't like this idea though because it will certainly cause a delay in loading, whereas using a CursorAdapter seems to be better for performance.

The way I was intending to display the tags within each listview item was just as plain text, linearly along the bottom of the row with different colours using Html.fromHtml(). I already have this part working so i was hoping to stick with the existing listview (if possible). My problem is purely about finding the best and most efficient way of getting the tags out of the DB and making them available to each row in the listview.

I'm very new to android - is there a clever way to do this or is it going to be a manual exercise?

Answer (score 0):

There's no shortcut for this. You're going to have to create a `View` by subclassing `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or whatever you want. In your `View` class expose a public method like 'setTag(tag)' which takes an argument as to what tag to set the corresponding data to. In your `View` you'll have to have some field which maintains a reference to that View. In other words, somewhere before you return your view in getView in your `Adapter`, you can bind the data to the View and then alter its state from within the `View`.